# replicate local mysql server to a cloud-based mysql

Tags: mysql, cloud, replication, google-cloud-sql

We have a local mysql server(not on public domain) and want that server replicated to a google cloud sql instance that we have. My question is that: 
1. is this possible? 
2. our local server is accessible on the local network only. no public IP, etc. Although the server has internet. Im not sure how replication works, is this a one way traffic from master to slave?

if this is the case, then this might be possible even if the local mysql server is not accessible on the public domain since it only need to connect to the slave up on the cloud.

hope this makes sense

Comment: slave reads from master, master doesn't push to slave.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL replication requires a connection from the slave to the master. The easiest way to make this possible is to set up a DMZ or port forwarding so your SQL instance is accessible over the internet.

Google Cloud SQL does not support replication from off-site to Cloud SQL, but you can do it with MySQL on GCE.

If you do use MySQL on GCE you have the added option of using [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn) to allow a connection from your GCE instance to your local MySQL instance without requiring public exposure of either.